# Update three.js Raycaster on window resize

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

I'm using a ray caster to select objects in my three.js scene. The objects in question are box geometry in the shape of flooring.

When I select an object the right object is selected, however when I then resize the window the raycaster still works off of where the objects originally were before I changed the window size, so I could select an object and nothing happens, or I could select no object and an object gets selected.

How do you update this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When resizing, you normally should do two things so raycasting still works:

- Updating the projection matrix of the camera
- Ensure to use the new window dimensions to compute the mouse coordinates

Both is done in the following official example [webgl_interactive_cubes](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes). The relevant code sections are:

```
function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

}
```